# HTML5 - Datepicker disable past dates without jQuery

Tags: php, html, datepicker

How should I disable past dates in the datepicker only using HTML?

Example: Suppose today it's 2000/12/21, this is how the datepicker should look.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 supports the `min` and `max` attribute.

Play around with the example below and you'll understand how it works!

```html
  Enter a date before 2000-12-21:
  <input type="date" name="example1" max="2000-12-20"><br>

  Enter a date after 2000-12-21:
  <input type="date" name="example2" min="2000-12-22"><br>
```

Just use PHP to automatically update the datepicker to the current date:

```
<input type="date" name="example3" min="<?= date('Y-m-d') ?>">
```

> **NOTE:** Internet Explorer 9 (and lower) doesn't support this feature.

Comment: It's much better to use a templating system like Twig and avoid mixing PHP and HTML, in which case the last code would become `<input type="date" name="example3" min="{{ 'now'|date('Y-m-d') }}">`